# Roth Conversion over ACA Cliff

Tags: united-states, taxes, roth-conversion, affordable-care-act

Since the ACA Cliff is eliminated for 2021 (& 2022), it appears to be a good time to do an extra large Roth Conversion.  Assuming the individual is already close to the ACA cliff (and not on SocSec, SSDI, etc.), are there any ACA issues to be aware of when surpassing the cliff?

Answer (score 1):

The cliff is temporarily gone, but the phasedown is extended to a phaseout, at a slightly lower rate.

Specifically, your Premium Tax Credit is limited to the SLCSP (Second Lowest Cost Silver Plan) Premium applicable to your location and demographics less 8.5% of your household MAGI. Using $10k as a round-number approximation to SLCSP (since I don't know yours) and assuming by individual you mean no spouse or dependents are present:

- with MAGI $50k (just under 400%FPL, the former cliff) your maximum credit is $5,750 (actually a hair more because the applicable percentage changes slightly, but this is imprecise anyway)
- with MAGI $60k due to adding a $10k conversion, the maximum is $4,900
- with MAGI $100k due to adding $50k, the maximum is $1,500
- with MAGI over about $120k you get no credit